# Is there any faster way to produce a plist in iOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I have a website that provide various place name and CCTV camera. 
The URL:http://www.gov.hk/en/theme/psi/datasets/trafficsnapshot.htm

For example, I would like to produce series of list named Hong Kong Island, Kowloon, Tsuen Wan and etc. Let's focus on the list of Hong Kong Island. I want a plist of NSDictionary containing various items with name and cameraCode. Name will contain Aberdeen Praya Road near Fish Market while cameraCode will contain H429F.JPG.

Is there any faster way to produce plist(s)?

Comment: Faster than what? How do you create the plist now?

Comment: I am now create the plist and add the items manually in xcode.

Actually, I have a sql file, is this possible to transform the plist file from sql file?

Comment: If they are XML plists, just write up a script to do it for you.  If they are binary plists, then you can write an OS X command line program to do it for you.

Comment: You could use Objective-C to get all data from your sql file and then write all data into your plist file.